# SQL Server JOIN returning multiple rows - need one row on left side

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I've Googled and tested extensively. I think I may have brain fade.

Our website has specific landing pages for various products.

The `Control` table holds the page title and product search information.

`Control`

```
ID       Title                Category        Colour
------------------------------------------------------------
1        Blue Postcards       Postcard        Blue
2        Blue Photos          Photo           Blue
3        Yellow Postcards     Postcard        Yellow
4        Postcards            Postcard        null
```

`Products`

```
pk_ProdID       Category         Price
-------------------------------------------
100             Postcard         59
200             Photo            42
300             Postcard         33
400             Photo            97
500             Postcard         78
600             Postcard         48
```

Each Product has records for zero or more colours it can be sold in.

`Products_Colours`

```
fk_ProdID  Colour
-------------------------
100        Blue
100        Yellow
200        Blue
300        Yellow
400        Red
500        Blue
500        Yellow
600        Blue
```

If the ID of `Control` is 1, the page should show Blue Postcards.

The following is the desired result:

```
ProdID         Category         Price
-------------------------------------------
100            Postcard         59
500            Postcard         78
600            Postcard         48
```

What I am actually getting is:

```
ProdID         Category         Price
-------------------------------------------
100            Postcard         59
100            Postcard         59
500            Postcard         78
500            Postcard         78
600            Postcard         48
```

**SQL**

This stored procedure returns two recordsets for my PHP page to reduce the number of requests to the database.

```
DECLARE @OrderBy varchar(1)
SET @OrderBy = 'D'
DECLARE @Row int
SET @Row = 1
DECLARE @ControlID int
SET @Control = 1

/* get control info for web page */
SELECT 
c.ID,
c.Title

FROM dbo.Control c

WHERE c.ID = @ControlID;

/* get search criteria */
WITH ControlSearch AS 
(
SELECT 
ID,
Category,
Colour
FROM Control WHERE ID = @ControlID
),

/* get products that match search criteria */
ProductSearch AS 
(
SELECT 
DISTINCT p.ProdID,       
p.Category
Count(1) OVER() As Total_Records,
   
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
   ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'D' THEN p.Price END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'U' THEN p.Price END ASC
    ) As RowNum       
       
   FROM dbo.Products p
   JOIN ControlSearch l ON l.ID = @ControlID
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Products_Colours co ON p.ProdID = co.ProdID
   WHERE
  
   (p.Category = l.Category)
   
   AND       
  
   (co.Colour = l.Colour OR l.Colour is null)
)   

/* return recordset */
SELECT * FROM ProductSearch WHERE RowNum >= @Row AND RowNum < (@Row + 50)
```

I display the total number of matching records to the user, and output row numbers so I can paginate by 50 products.

Why does this return multiple Products according to how many colours it has?

Comment: *"Why does this return multiple Products according to how many colours it has?"* Because that's how joins work. If you have 1 row related to 2 rows, and you `JOIN` the 1 row to the 2, you get 2 rows. Much like if you have 2 rows related to 4 rows, you get 8 rows when you `JOIN`.

Comment: Why put the clauses `p.Category = l.Category` and `co.Colour = l.Colour` in the `WHERE` and not the appropriate `ON` clauses for their `JOIN`s? It makes far more sense, for example, to have `JOIN ControlSearch l ON p.Category = l.Category` and then have `WHERE l.ID = @ControlID`.

Comment: How would I change it to return only 1 row for each product that matches?

Comment: Why `JOIN` to `dbo.Products_Colours` at all here, when you don't actually have use of the table?

Comment: Larnu - because I think if I put it in the JOIN I cannot do searches if Control.Colour is null. Some pages show all Postcards, no matter what colour they are.

Comment: That depends, which "1 row for each product" do you want, and why? Why should it pick blue over yellow or vice-versa? And don't say it doesn't matter; SQL Server doesn't have an `ARBITRARY` feature.

Comment: I want to return all products that match the criteria stated in the Control table. Whether that's Postcards of ANY colour, or Postcards that can be blue or yellow or red or ..... I don't know how to answer you, Aaron. Sorry. I just know I want one row for each product that matches.

Comment: Larnu - because when I ask for Control ID 1, it's searching for Postcards that have a Blue colour in the joined table? It's not looking for Blue Photos? I am confused.

Comment: You're probably thinking "why's he being stupid?" but I do not know what I do not know. You're asking me why I am doing something in a particular way. This is the way I think it should be done because it's what I know, but it's clearly wrong. I was hoping someone could point out "you don't do it like that.... you do it like this..." and then I could learn.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stab in the dark, but perhaps what you really want here is an `EXISTS`:

```sql
DECLARE @ControlID int
SET @ControlID = 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Products P
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Control C
                   LEFT JOIN dbo.Products_Colours PC ON C.Colour = PC.Colour
              WHERE C.Category = P.Category
                AND PC.fk_ProdID = P.pk_ProdID
                AND (PC.Colour IS NOT NULL OR C.Colour IS NULL)
                AND C.ID = @ControlID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this

```
SELECT
  p.ProdID,       
  p.Category,
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total_Records,
  CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'U'
    THEN COUNT(*) OVER () - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.Price) + 1
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.Price) END
    AS RowNum   
FROM dbo.Products P
JOIN dbo.Control C ON C.ID = @ControlID  -- single-row cross join
WHERE C.Category = P.Category
  AND (
    C.Colour IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.Products_Colours PC
        WHERE C.Colour = PC.Colour
          AND PC.fk_ProdID = P.pk_ProdID)
  );
```